# Java socket programming - Wont work in Android 4.1?

Tags: java, android, sockets, socketexception, android-4.2-jelly-bean

In my Android project I just have one Activity - "MainActivity.java". I added another class file in the same package "GetSocket.java".

Functionality of GetSocket.java is it will return a string via Socket connection to a particular server hosted in a website. GetSocket.java works just fine if run alone as a Java Application.

But when I call it using from the Android Activity, it doesn't return me the intended message, it just gets failed with an exception for which I'm unable to get StackTrace as well.

Mind you this is the outcome when ran in Android 4.1 version.

But the same code works in Android 2.2 and gets me the intended message.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity
{
TextView t= (TextView) getViewById(R.id.textView1);
//..
//some code
//..
String msg=GetSocket.getMessage();

//..
//some more code
//
}
```

GetSocket.java

```
public class GetSocket
{
 public static String getMessage()
 {
  String b;
  Socket s=new Socket("<IP-Address",<Port-number>);
  InputStream i=s.getInputStream();
  int length=i.read(b)
  return b;
 }
}
```

Comment: Read about NetworkOnMainThreadException. There are several posts in SO about this.

Comment: +1 for NetworkOnMainThreadException.  One way to avoid this exception is to use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) -- it has worked fine for my socket applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry about the late response. Found the problem to my solution. 
From 4.0 Android doesn't allow socket programming through the UI thread. I used Async Task to hand the socket in a separate background thread. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

Check your manifest for internet permission :)