# Why normal Java socket programming does not work in Android?

Tags: android

When I use normal Java socket programming in Android, the app crashes.

```
Socket sock=new Socket(Ip,Port);
DataInputStream din=new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java socket programming - Wont work in Android 4.1?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380850/java-socket-programming-wont-work-in-android-4-1)

Comment: All the networking task should be out of main thread ,it will work if work other than main ui thread

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot run network operations in UI Thread, so start another Thread, or use AsyncTask, or anything else. Another reason could be permissions, add these lines in your manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`